# PDE: wave equation inhomogenous boundary problem: Where the C^2 gone?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading W. Strauss' PDE book. While studiyng wave equation inhomogenous problem I stucked at this place: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC8bK.png).
When we computed $$w_{n}(t)$$ in terms of $$u_{n}(t), \pi, k(t), h(t)$$ and then substituted this to $$v_{n}(t)-c^2w_{n}(t)=f_{n}(t)$$, and then expanded, we get $$c^2$$ factor at LHS with $$v_{n}$$, (i.e. $$c^2\lambda_{n}v_{n}$$ ) but no $$c^2$$ on RHS.
The question is -- where the $$c^2$$ on RHS gone?